# Remove empty string from the text in python

Tags: python, string

I am writing a program that processes on the text individually. I am extracting the text by using the below code.

```
words= re.sub(r"[^a-z']+",' ',text).upper().lstrip()
```

The output I am getting is like below. But I also want to remove the space between two lines. But I also want to remove the empty line between for example  `I AM FINE` and `THANK YOU`.

```
HI
HOW ARE YOU
I AM FINE

THANK YOU

AND YOU.
```

How can I remove this empty string from the text?

Desired output is

```
HI
HOW ARE YOU
I AM FINE
THANK YOU
AND YOU.
```

Comment: Has it to be with regex? Do you want to have a list of the words? Or do you just want the empty lines removed?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: I just want to remove empty lines @CodePope

Comment: I have updated question @tomjn

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
text = """HI
HOW ARE YOU
I AM FINE

THANK YOU

AND YOU."""


words = re.sub(r"(?<=\n)\W+", '', text)
print(words)
```

This prints:

```
HI
HOW ARE YOU
I AM FINE
THANK YOU
AND YOU.
```

You can test the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/HjFWaL/1).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `split` and `join` to remove the empty strings?
Example:

```
s="""HI
HOW ARE YOU

I AM FINE
THANK YOU
AND YOU. """

output = '\n'.join(line for line in s.split('\n') if line)
print(output)
```

Output:

```
HI
HOW ARE YOU
I AM FINE
THANK YOU
AND YOU.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `.replace('\n', '')` to your `words= re.sub(r"[^a-z']+",' ',text).upper().lstrip()` if you want to keep your code as it is. This will replace an empty line aka enter with nothing.

Combined code: `words= re.sub(r"[^a-z']+",' ',text).upper().lstrip().replace('\n', '')`

EDIT: Short explanation

Answer (score 0):

You could try `text.replace('\n\n', '\n')` to remove double new-lines.

```
words = re.sub(r"[^a-z']+",' ',text.replace('\n\n', '\n')).upper().lstrip()
```

Or, in case there may be unknown number of new-lines, try:

```
while '\n\n' in text:
    text = text.replace('\n\n', '\n')
words = re.sub(r"[^a-z']+",' ',text).upper().lstrip() # original code
```